# Entity Framework, get list for database first case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use Entity framework for most of my applications, but they are all code-first.

Now I am dealing with a pre existing database.

I am being able of finding, updating, and adding records through DbContext.

```
public class CompanyService
{
    public void AddCompany(Company cpn)
    {
        CompanyModel cm = new CompanyModel();
        cm.Companies.Add(cpn);
        cm.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void EditCompany(Company cpn)
    {
        CompanyModel cm = new CompanyModel();
        company existing = cm.Companies.Find(cpn.id);
        cm.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(cpn);
        cm.SaveChanges();
    }

    public List<Company> List()
    {
        CompanyModel cm = new CompanyModel();

    }
}
```

`CompanyModel` is a class such that `CompanyModel : DbContext`, my bad.

But `CompanyModel` is very limited, it does not have a `Where` method.

How can I get a list of `Company`.

Comment: Do you mean like this `new CompanyModel().Companies.ToList()` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I was looking for, but it is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code file. This will enable you to use the Linq extensions like `ToList()`.